# How can one find the "maximized" height of a browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a picture take up 70% of the user's screen.  However, if the screen is made smaller when the page is loaded or if the person has inspect element open, the picture becomes small and stretched.  I believe the best solution would be to find the maximum height of the browser window and make the image that size.  However, I am not sure how to do that?

Here is my current code for image sizing:

```
var topoffset = window.innerHeight * 0.77;
var profilestart = topoffset - $(".prof-header").height();
$('.splashPic').css("height", topoffset);
$('.splashPlaceholder').css("top", profilestart);
```

I also want to make it so that if someone is using a huge monitor (i.e. large Mac), the image size maxes out at that point?  Any suggestions would be very helpful!

**Edit:** I don't want to make the image resize dynamically.  Only load once.

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.screen.availHeight` instead of `window.innerHeight`

or `screen.height`

```
var x = screen.height*0.7;
```

EDIT: Here's more code to show that it works for what you asked.  Gets the height upon load and doesn't resize.

```
<img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240/food" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = screen.height*0.7;
    $('#img2').css("height",x);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works.  If you used this or it helped you mark answer as accepted please.  If you didn't use this, can you show what you did?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is something like this:

```
img{
    display:block;
    width:70%;
    min-width:320px;
    max-width:1200px;
}
```

Comment: i am looking to fix the height, not the width

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to take up 70% of the viewport height (and obviously retain its ratio) you could use the new css unit `vh` (viewport height) like this:

```
img
{
    height: 70vh;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5e3vk/)**